# How to make a Request with local files in the payload?

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm trying to make a PUT request with a payload that contains an URL of a PNG file, but this PNG file is locally stored.

Instead of using my local URI, I'm using the open method like this:

```
open('images/path-to-image/image-1.png', 'rb')
```

This is the complete code:

```
order_number = 99
item_number = 12345678
url = f"https://api.printful.com/orders/@{order_number}"

payload={
'items': [
    {'external_id': str(item_number),
     'files': [
         {'url': open('images/path-to-image/image-1.png', 'rb'), 
          'position': {
              'area_width': 3000, 
              'area_height': 4000, 
              'width': 3000, 
              'height': 4000, 
              'top': 0, 
              'left': 0}
         }
     ]
    }
]
}
headers = {
'Authorization': 'Bearer PRIVATE-KEY'
}

response = requests.request("PUT", url, headers=headers, json=payload)json=payload)
res = response.json()

print(f"Order {order_number}, Code result: {res['code']}")
```

But I receive the following error:

`TypeError: Object of type BufferedReader is not JSON serializable`

This code works if I delete the open method and using any PNG image URL from the web.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to use a local file to make a put request instead of using an external URL?

Comment: You need the actual data stored in the image file.  Change it to `open('images/path-to-image/image-1.png', 'rb').read()`

Comment: I just tried with read method and got this error: `Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable`